# How to include tables in a Swagger API

Tags: asp.net, swagger

I am building (trying) an ASP.NET Core Web API  to access a database with tree tables via API.

[image]

Person-Employee linked via LastName column, Employee-Roles linked via Admins

I created the models via Scaffold tool so by default the  Person class includes  a property list of employees

```
public virtual ICollection(Employees) Employee { get; set; } = new List<Employees>();
```

I can now include it in the GET method as follows:

```
[HttpGet]   
public async Task<IEnumerable(Pesrson)> Get() => await _context.Persons.Include(c => c.Employees).ToListAsync();
```

This works!-So question is:

How do I include the Roles?

I added a property to the Person class

```
public virtual ICollection (Roles) Roles { get; set; } = new List<Role>();
```

and run `PM>Add-Migration`

Compiles without errors but this generates an error (Swagger) because still wants to link via `LastName`. The Roles table does not have a column named `LastName`.

I also thing that manually adding the property Roles may change the actual schema.  Any help is greatly appreciated